# VBA listbox "select" items but remains with a value of "", randomly

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am struggling with an Excel VBA userform.

Quick explanation, I have 5 userform.listbox that can either manually filled or copied from a template generated from labels

when i use the macro to copy the template, the listbox are selected as intended but the value in the background remains "" for 2 out of the 5 boxes.... and not always the same. i need to manually click on the highlighted item to generate the value.

DD_ are my listbox,

EX_ are my labels

```
Dim ValueNewShrink As String 
Dim ValueGroup As String 
Dim ValueType As String 
Dim ValuePayType As String 
Dim ValueGroupType As String

ValueNewShrink = Validation.EX_NewShrink.Caption
Validation.DD_NewShrink.Value = ValueNewShrink

ValueGroup = Validation.EX_Group.Caption 
Validation.DD_Group.Value = ValueGroup

ValueType = Validation.EX_Type.Caption 
Validation.DD_Type.Value = ValueType

ValuePayType = Validation.EX_PayType.Caption
Validation.DD_PayType.Value = ValuePayType

ValueGroupType = Validation.EX_GroupType.Caption
Validation.DD_GroupType.Value = ValueGroupType
```

so Always 3 out of 5 works,

2 never populate the value, not always the same and when I put a breakpoint and add watch to analyse, the EX_*.caption has text associated to it but the DD_*.value = "", the other 3, have the same caption, variable and value the weird thing is, the right listbox is selected in my form.....

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was not able to pinpoint the reason, I am searching if its blank and if it is im populating with the label.

```
If NewCodeFound.DD_NewShrink.Text <> "" Then
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("C10").Value = NewCodeFound.DD_NewShrink.Text
Else
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("C10").Value = NewCodeFound.EX_NewShrink.Caption
End If


If NewCodeFound.DD_Group.Text <> "" Then
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("D10").Value = NewCodeFound.DD_Group.Text
Else
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("D10").Value = NewCodeFound.EX_Group.Caption
End If

If NewCodeFound.DD_Type.Text <> "" Then
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("E10").Value = NewCodeFound.DD_Type.Text
Else
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("E10").Value = NewCodeFound.EX_Type.Caption
End If

If NewCodeFound.DD_PayType.Text <> "" Then
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("F10").Value = NewCodeFound.DD_PayType.Text
Else
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("F10").Value = NewCodeFound.EX_PayType.Caption
End If

If NewCodeFound.DD_GroupType.Text <> "" Then
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("G10").Value = NewCodeFound.DD_GroupType.Text
Else
Worksheets("Email new code").Range("G10").Value = NewCodeFound.EX_GroupType.Caption
End If
```